# How to load other Jquery version in Yii2 and keep yiactiveform function for validation of fields?

Tags: yii2

When I load Jquery from CDN, it is working but the problem is I cant do validation of fields that are defined in rules() method. But when I don't 
 load custom Jquery version from CDN then validation is working.

Also, I am getting **jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function** in the console when I load Jquery from CDN and if I use inbuilt Jquery then no error.

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: Jquery is loaded by yii assets

Comment: When you add custom jQuery version from CDN, how do you remove inbuilt jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.noConflict for your second, non-yii jQuery and use another var name instead of $. In this example i use *jq*

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

// Do something with jQuery
jq( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$( ".content" ).hide();
```

You can add this line in your template after your  tag with jQuery.

```
<script>var jq = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

If you use an Asset, just load an additional .js script with that line.

Anyway, **you should avoid this entirely if you can**.

From the documentation:

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
>   recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version
>   will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
>   version.